# How to make the grid content to be viewed with out varying the size

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi all i am having a text file which consists of some data and each and every line in that particular is fixed to 94. Now when the user opened the particular text file and if my condition satisfies i will show it to datagridview. But when displaying to datagridview even the length of each and every line is 94 the content displaying in grid varies why it is happening . How to make sure that each and every row in datagridview should be displayed in a constant way

[image]

Any idea please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a non-proportional font in the grid, which means that not all characters have the same size. F.e. spaces are way shorter then the 0. Use a proportional font, and the lines will be the same length.

**Edit:** Let's have a look at an example:

> This is a non-proportional font,
> the line will have different lengths,
> though they are 10 characters long:
> 1234567890
> adilngvzus

```
Now let's look at a proportional font:

1234567890
adilngvzus
```

As you can see, in a proportional font (like your IDE is most likely using) every characters has the same width. In a non-proportional font (like your text-processor is most likely using by default) the characters are varying in width, making the `i` one of the 'thinest' and the `O` one of the 'widest' characters.

Comment: What does it mean by proportional and non proportional font

Comment: @Dorababu: Added further explanation.

Comment: How can i over come this where i have to do changes now

Comment: @Dorababu: Change the default font of the column to a proportional font like `DejaVu Sans Mono` or `Courier New`.

Comment: Are there any other, can i have a list of all Proportional font

Comment: @Dorababu: (A little hacky ahead) You can see all those Fonts if you create a new `FontDialog`, and set the `FixedPitchOnly` property to `True`.

Comment: @Bobby : i need another help for the same in gridview how can we fix this